# How to build a multidimensional array from the Json decoded output?

Tags: php, array

What I'm trying to achieve is to build the array that should match exactly the structure of an Json decoded version. I am stuck where I need to address indexed array within an array. It would be a great help if someone could help me cross where I'm stuck.

```
// Array to be built to match JSON decoded version of associative array.
$fulfillment_array['orderShipment']['orderLines']['orderLine'] = [];

    foreach ($fulfillment_records as $this_fulfillment_record) {
        // Assemble the fulfillment array for Walmart.
        $fulfillment_array['orderShipment']['orderLines']['orderLine'][] = array(
            "lineNumber" =>
            "sellerOrderId" =>
            "orderLineStatuses" => array(
                "orderLineStatus" => array (
                    // Is this the right way of addressing an indexed array to match the structure of associative array below.
                    array (
                        "status" => "Shipped",
                        "statusQuantity" => array(
                            "unitOfMeasurement" => "Each",
                            "amount" => 
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );
```

The Associative array that I am trying to build with my code above is

```
Array
(
    [orderShipment] => Array
        (
            [orderLines] => Array
                (
                    [orderLine] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [lineNumber] => 1
                                    [sellerOrderId] => 92344
                                    [orderLineStatuses] => Array
                                        (
                                            [orderLineStatus] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [status] => Shipped
                                                            [statusQuantity] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [unitOfMeasurement] => EACH
                                                                    [amount] => 1
                                                                )

                                                            [trackingInfo] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [shipDateTime] => 1580821866000
                                                                    [carrierName] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [otherCarrier] => 
                                                                            [carrier] => UPS
                                                                        )

                                                                    [methodCode] => Standard
                                                                    [trackingNumber] => 22344
                                                                    [trackingURL] => http://walmart/tracking/ups?&type=MP&seller_id=12345&promise_date=03/02/2020&dzip=92840&tracking_numbers=92345
                                                                )

                                                            [returnCenterAddress] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [name] => walmart
                                                                    [address1] => walmart store 2
                                                                    [address2] => 
                                                                    [city] => Huntsville
                                                                    [state] => AL
                                                                    [postalCode] => 35805
                                                                    [country] => USA
                                                                    [dayPhone] => 12344
                                                                    [emailId] => walmart@walmart.com
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [lineNumber] => 2
                                    [sellerOrderId] => 92344
                                    [orderLineStatuses] => Array
                                        (
                                            [orderLineStatus] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [status] => Shipped
                                                            [statusQuantity] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [unitOfMeasurement] => EACH
                                                                    [amount] => 1
                                                                )

                                                            [trackingInfo] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [shipDateTime] => 1580821866000
                                                                    [carrierName] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [otherCarrier] => 
                                                                            [carrier] => FedEx
                                                                        )

                                                                    [methodCode] => Express
                                                                    [trackingNumber] => 22344
                                                                    [trackingURL] => http://walmart/tracking/fedEx?&type=MP&seller_id=12345&promise_date=03/02/2020&dzip=92840&tracking_numbers=92344
                                                                )

                                                            [returnCenterAddress] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [name] => walmart
                                                                    [address1] => walmart store 2
                                                                    [address2] => 
                                                                    [city] => Huntsville
                                                                    [state] => AL
                                                                    [postalCode] => 35805
                                                                    [country] => USA
                                                                    [dayPhone] => 12344
                                                                    [emailId] => walmart@walmart.com
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this link solution :-

- **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39250602/how-to-create-multidimensional-array-using-a-foreach-loop-in-php**
- **https://www.elated.com/php-multidimensional-arrays/**

I think help this link.

**`THANKS.`**